# Ellipses aspect ratio line/band profile imageJ/Gnuplot/Python?

Tags: python, gnuplot, aspect-ratio, imagej, ellipse

I am working with several thousands of fitted ellipses on an image. After the fitting procedure the obtained results table consist of all the parameters of ellipses such as aspect ratio and angle etc. I would like to measure a band on the image as a line profile which consists of for example 700-1000 ellipses. Is it possible to get a line profile which looks like exactly the same as a grey scale intensity or the RGB profile but instead of grey value the y axis of the line profile shows the aspect ratio of the ellipses in the selected area or the major axis lenght or angle or anything written in the ellipse fitting results table? The x axis remains the same the distance. I have tried to do many things but based on my experience this function is not included in ImageJ. Is it possible to solve this problem with imagej or gnuplot or witor with a python script if I have all parameters of ellipses? To sum up, I would like to draw a band on the image and get a line profile based on the lenght of the band (x axis) and the aspect ratios of ellipses (y axis). Thank is advance!

I tried everything with imageJ I am sure it is not included in the software.

Image for better understanding:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Sorry, I can't follow your description. Please show your image and some example data. What do you mean with "band on the image" and the "selected area"? How do you select the 700-1000 ellipses out of your several thousands? What about the grey value? I'm pretty confused. Please clarify!

Comment: so I created an image for better understanding. https://imgur.com/a/agg9Wsu

I have fitted approx. 10k ellipses to an image (left figure: I zoomed into the image and selected a rectangle area highlighted by yellow colour). Here you can see that ellipses are grouped into bands and I would like to measure the aspect ratio distribution of ellipses in this selected area as a function of distance. I would like to acquire a line profile (rather a "band" profile because it gives better statistics with more ellipses) which looks like the greyscale line profil which is on the top-right figure.

Comment: I have all parameters of ellipses from the fitting procedure (bottom-right figure shows a part of the parameter table) aspect ratio, area, major and minor axes and so on. To som up, I would like to measure the change of the ellipse aspect ratio (or angle between major and minor axes of each ellipse or any kind of ellipse parameter) as a function of distance and important that ONLY in the selected area. My main problem is that I can only measure this on the whole image. Thanks in advance if you have any idea how to solve my problem.

Comment: Thanks for the additions. I assume you define your rectangle by center point, a rotation angle and the two sides. So, what I see in your marked rectangle (what you probably called "bands") are 7 alternating "bands" between more "lengthy" and more "round" ellipses. So, do I understand correctly that you want a plot which shows the length,angle, quantity perimeter, etc. as function along your rectangle middle line? But I still don't understand what the grey value in your inset image are. Could you please provide some test data/table to play with? It will be difficult to create random test data.

Comment: What is the difference between x,y and xm,ym? They seem to be the same in your screenshot.

Comment: Yes you are right, that is what I need, but let's make it simple and forget any other parameters of ellipses and consider only the aspect ratio of ellipses inside the rectangle. I need a line profil which is crossing through these bands with ellipse with different average aspect ratio and make a graph were the x-axis is the line or band which is crossing through the ellipses and y-axis show the average aspect ratio. And your second question, honestly I don't know what is xm and ym, x and y is the coordinate of the ellipse. Btw I am new here how can I send data or a table or anything?

Comment: Oh and the other thing related to the grey-scale line profile image, so basically I put there as an example to show that I need exactly the same line profile where x-axis shows the long dimension of the line or rectagle what i draw and y-axis shows the average aspect ratio of ellipses at the given distance

Comment: I'm not sure what the best way would be to provide data. If the data is not too large you could add it as text to your question (formatted as code, i.e. enclosed between two triple backquotes) or maybe at pastebin.com and post the link here.

Comment: Problem solved? Question answered? Any response would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In case I've understood your question correctly...

- you have data of thousands of ellipses in a table (it would be good to have the data, but since I didn't have it, the script below creates some "random" data itself. Don't worry too much about how the data is created.) The data columns are `xm, ym, dmax, dmin, angle`.
- define a rectangle by two points P0 and P1 a width `w`, i.e. variables: `x0,y0,x1,y1,w`
- define functions which determine the distance of a point from a line (see e.g. [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_from_a_point_to_a_line)). Whereas `distRY(xm,ym)` is the (perpendicular) distance from the arrow, `distRX(xm,ym)` is the (perpendicular) distance from a line rotated by 90° relative to the arrow in P0, which is basically the distance from P0 along the arrow or in other words the x-coordinate for your analysis plot.
- define a function `insideRect(xm,ym)` which returns if a given point (center of ellipse) is inside (=1) the rectangle or not (=0)
- define a color function `myColor(xm,ym)` which colors the ellipses differently depending on if they are inside or outside the rectangle
- plot your data as overview with marked rectangle and arrow

Now comes the main part:

- plot the data where the x-value is the distance `dx` from P0 along the line and as y-value the the ellipse aspect ratio `$4/$3`, but only if the ellipse center coordinates `xm,ym` (or `$1,$2` from your table/file) are inside the rectangle, otherwise plot nothing, i.e. `NaN`. Since the ellipses are random in order you need to sort the data by distance `dx`. Unfortunatly, earlier gnuplot versions had no internal sorting feature, but from gnuplot 5.4.0 on, you have the option `smooth zsort` which you can use for that. However, this apparently works only with plotting style `with points`. That's why you have to plot it to a table first `$Temp` and then plot this table `with lines`. Although, with gnuplot5.5, it looks like you can plot it directly `with lines` without having to plot it to a table first.

Maybe it's not so easy to understand. Check `help zsort`, `help ternary`, `help lc variable`, and in general `help <keyword>` for further reading.

**Script:** (works for gnuplot>=5.4.0, because the use of `smooth zsort`)

```
### analysis of ellipses in selected rectangle
reset session

# create some random test data
set print $Data
    do for [i=1:1000] {
        x0 = rand(0)*400
        y0 = rand(0)*400
        b = abs(x0+y0)/150.-floor(abs(x0+y0)/150.) < 0.5 
        ratio = b ? rand(0)*0.4+0.8 : rand(0)*0.5+2.75
        dmax = b ? rand(0)*2+9 : rand(0)*10+25
        dmin = dmax/ratio
        a0   = rand(0)*10-40
        print sprintf("%g %g %g %g %g",x0,y0,dmax,dmin,a0)
    }
set print

# define your selection rectangle
x0 = 100
y0 = 100
x1 = 300
y1 = 300
w  = 100
x2 = x0+y0-y1
y2 = y0-x0+x1

set size ratio -1
set angles degrees
set xrange[0:400]
set yrange[0:400]
set tics out
set key noautotitle

a0 = atan2(y1-y0,x1-x0)
L0 = sqrt((x1-x0)**2 + (y1-y0)**2)

distRY(xm,ym)     = abs((x1-x0)*(y0-ym) - (x0-xm)*(y1-y0))/L0
distRX(xm,ym)     =    ((x2-y0)*(y0-ym) - (x0-xm)*(y2-y0))/L0
insideRect(xm,ym) = distRX(xm,ym)>=0 && distRX(xm,ym)<=L0 && distRY(xm,ym)<=w*0.5
myColor(xm,ym)    = insideRect(xm,ym) ? 0x008000 : 0xcccccc

set multiplot layout 2,1

    # plot original data with selection and arrow
    set obj 1 polygon from x0-w*0.5*sin(a0),y0+w*0.5*cos(a0) rto w*sin(a0), -w*cos(a0) \
         rto L0*cos(a0),L0*sin(a0) rto -w*sin(a0),w*cos(a0) \
         to x0-w*0.5*sin(a0),y0+w*0.5*cos(a0) lw 2 fs solid fc rgb 0x77ffff00
    plot $Data u 1:2:3:4:5:(myColor($1,$2)) w ellipses lw 0.5 lc rgb var, \
           '+' u (x0):(y0):(x1-x0):(y1-y0) every ::::0 w vec lw 1.5 lc "red"

    # plot data within rectangle as function along arrow
    set xlabel "position along arrow"
    set xrange[0:L0]
    set ylabel "ratio dmax/dmin"
    set yrange[*:*]
    set size noratio
    unset obj 1
    set datafile missing NaN
    set origin 0.0,0.15
    set size 1.0,0.25
    set table $Temp
        plot $Data u (dx=distRX($1,$2)):(insideRect($1,$2)?$3/$4:NaN):(dx) smooth zsort
    unset table
    plot $Temp u 1:2 w l lc "web-green"

unset multiplot
### end of script
```

**Result:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

With ImageJ,

1. Make a rectangular region (a rotated rectangular selection) that defines a slot (just a "slice" of the yellow area).
2. Determine which ellipse centers are in this region.
3. Compute the average of the desired parameter of these ellipses.
4. Move the rectangular region by one slot-width along the long axis of the yellow area and start again with #2.

A short clip shows how a moving slot could look like.
[image]

First draw a line that defines the direction of the slot movement, then an ImageJ-macro defines the size and positions of the slot along the line.

For every slot position the parameters of the enclosed ellipses can be averaged and plotted.